# Trying to use dcc.Dropdown (multi = True) to show/hide html.Div elements in Dash-Plotly (Python)

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Currently trying to create a sports team stats page that will allow the coaches to pick and choose which players to look at.  The idea is that I want to have a multi-dropdown list at the top that shows/hides players based on what's picked.

Below is the code I have so far (ignore the fact that I have NumPy and Pandas loaded; planning on doing some other stuff with that later...):

```py
from os import name
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

player_list = [
    "player-1",
    "player-2"
]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#server = app.server() # Put back in once you are ready to deply to Heroku

app.layout = html.Div([

    # navigation bar
    html.Div(
        className = "nav-container",
        children = [
            
            html.Nav(
                className = "nav",
                children = [
   
                    html.A(
                        "Home",
                        className = "a",
                        href="#"
                    ),
                    
                    html.Div(
                        className="dropdown",
                        children = [
                            
                            html.Button(
                                "About the Team",
                                className = "dropbtn"
                            ),
                            
                            html.Div(
                                className = "dropdown-content",
                                children = [
                                    html.A(
                                        "Team Stats",
                                        href = " "
                                    ),
                                    html.A(
                                        "PLACEHOLDER",
                                        href = " "
                                    )
                                ]
                            )
                        ]
                    ),
                    html.Div(
                        className="dropdown",
                        children = [
                            html.Button(
                                "PLACEHOLDER",
                                className = "dropbtn"
                            ),
                            html.Div(
                                className = "dropdown-content",
                                children = [
                                    html.A(
                                        "PLACEHOLDER",
                                        href = " "
                                    ),
                                    html.A(
                                        "PLACEHOLDER",
                                        href = " "
                                    )
                                ]
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            ),
        ]
    ),

    # Welcome header
    html.Div([
        html.H1(
            "Welcome to the Team Divergent Stats Page!",
            className = "welcome-header"
        )
    ]),

    html.Br(),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = "dropdown-to-show_or_hide-player",
        options = [
            {"label": "player-1", "value": "player-1"},
            {"label": "player-2", "value": "player-2"}
        ],
        value = None,
        multi = True
    ),

    html.Br(),

    # player card
    html.Div(
        id = "player-1",
        style = {"display": "none"},
        children = [
            html.Div(
                className = "player-card",
                children = [

                    html.Div( #player pic/avatar
                        className = "player-avatar",
                        children = [
                            html.H2("player-1 - POSITION"),
                            html.Hr(),
                            html.Img(src = " ", alt = "player-image")
                        ]
                    )
            ]),
            
            html.Div(
                children = [
                    html.Div( # player stats card
                        className = "player-stats-1",
                        children = [

                            html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                ),

                html.Div( # player stats card
                    className = "player-stats-2",
                    children = [

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        )
                    ]),

                html.Div( # player stats card
                    className = "player-stats-2",
                    children = [

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")
                            ]
                        )          
                    ]
                )   
            ]),
            html.Br(),
            html.Hr(),
            html.Br()   
        ]
    ),

    # player card
    html.Div(
        id = "player-2",
        style = {"display": "none"},
        children = [
            html.Div(
                className = "player-card",
                children = [

                    html.Div( #player pic/avatar
                        className = "player-avatar",
                        children = [
                            html.H2("player-2 - POSITION"),
                            html.Hr(),
                            html.Img(src = " ", alt = "player-image")
                        ]
                    )
            ]),
            
            html.Div(
                children = [
                    html.Div( # player stats card
                        className = "player-stats-1",
                        children = [

                            html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                ),

                html.Div( # player stats card
                    className = "player-stats-2",
                    children = [

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        ),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]
                        )
                    ]),

                html.Div( # player stats card
                    className = "player-stats-2",
                    children = [

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")   
                            ]),

                        html.Div(
                            className = "player-stats-card",
                            children = [
                                html.H4("Stat"),
                                html.Hr(),
                                html.P("Stat Value")
                            ]
                        )          
                    ]
                )   
            ]),
            html.Br(),
            html.Hr(),
            html.Br()   
        ]
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output("player-1", "style"),
    [Input("dropdown-to-show_or_hide-player", "value")]
)
def show_hide_player1(value):
    if value == ["player-1"]:
        return {"display": "block"}
    else: 
        return {"display": "none"}

@app.callback(
    Output("player-2", "style"),
    [Input("dropdown-to-show_or_hide-player", "value")]
)
def show_hide_player2(value):
    if value == ["player-2"]:
        return {"display": "block"}
    else: 
        return {"display": "none"}
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So far, I have gotten it to the point where if either "player-1" OR "player-2" are chosen in the top multi-dropdown menu, it works fine ("player-1" stats show up when "player-1" is chosen, etc).  However, whenever I have BOTH "player-1" and "player-2" selected, nothing shows up.

Any insight into how to make this work as intended?

Thanks.

-Edit:

Below is my stylesheet, so you can see exactly what I'm seeing when it loads:

```
/* Overall top navbar style */
.nav-container {
    background: #333;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.nav {
    background: #333;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.nav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav div {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.nav a:hover, .dropdown:hover, .dropbtn:hover {
    background-color: #F76900;
    color: black;
}


/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: "Verdana"; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
    margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F76900;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Verdana";
}
  
/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}
  
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
color: black;
}

/* For standalone buttons */
.button {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

/* For App container (to align them */
.app-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

/* For individual app cards */
.app-card {
    flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.app-card img {
    border-radius: 20%;
}

.app-card:hover {
    background: darkgray;
}

.title-p {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: wavy;
}

.banner-img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.banner-img-container img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
}

.intro-container {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.intro-card {
    flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.intro-card p {
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.intro-card hr {
    width: 60%;
}

.skill-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.skill-card {
    flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.skill-icon-img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Need to find the tutorial with the stacked timeline */
.timeline-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.closing-statement-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.text-block {
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.header2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.header2-p {
    text-align: center;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timeline {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
  
/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timeline::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: black;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
  
/* Container around content */
.container {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 50%;
}
  
/* The circles on the timeline */
.container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: -17px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
    top: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
  
/* Place the container to the left */
.left {
    left: -6.75%;
}
  
/* Place the container to the right */
.right {
    left: 50%;
}
  
/* Add arrows to the left container (pointing right) */
.left::before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 30px;
    border: medium solid black;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent lightgrey;
}
  
/* Add arrows to the right container (pointing left) */
.right::before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 30px;
    border: medium solid black;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent lightgrey transparent transparent;
}
  
/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.right::after {
    left: -16px;
}
  
/* The actual content */
.content {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
  
/* Media queries - Responsive timeline on screens less than 600px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/* Place the timelime to the left */
    .timeline::after {
    left: 31px;
}
  
/* Full-width containers */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
  
/* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
.container::before {
    left: 60px;
    border: medium solid black;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
  
/* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
.left::after, .right::after {
    left: 15px;
}

/* Make all right containers behave like the left ones */
.right {
    left: 0%;
}}

.signature-block {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.signature-block img {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.welcome-header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 75px;
}

.team-picture {
    text-align: center;
}

.coach-info {
    text-align: center;
}

.player-card {
    display: inline;
}

.player-avatar {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 30%;
    height: 425px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px lightgrey;
}

.player-avatar hr {
    width: 50%;
}

.player-avatar img {
    width: 30%;
    height: 425px;
    margin: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.player-stats.container {
    display: inline;
}

.player-stats-1 {
    display: flex;
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
    width: 67%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.player-stats-2 {
    display: flex;
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
    width: 67%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 445px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.player-stats-card {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px lightgrey;
    float: right;
}

.player-stats-card h6 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.player-stats-card p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (maybe not the best solution, but it's a solution)!!!

Below is the format for the `@app.callback()`'s that I was able to jerry-rig to make it work like I wanted.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("player-1", "style"),
    [Input("dropdown-to-show_or_hide-player", "value")]
)
def show_hide_player1(value):
    if "player-1" in value:
        return {"display": "block"}
    else:
        return {"display": "none"}
        

@app.callback(
    Output("player-2", "style"),
    [Input("dropdown-to-show_or_hide-player", "value")]
)
def show_hide_player2(value):
    if "player-2" in value:
        return {"display": "block"}
    else:
        return {"display": "none"}
```

With this solution, one would have to create an `@app.callback()` and `show_hide_player"X", which will allow each element's style attributes to be altered independently of the others.

For now, this solution works for me, but I', very interested to see if there is a better, more economical/streamlined way to do it!!  I'm 100% sure that my way is not the best way.